# Optical drive failing at specific disc locations: bad drive or bad disc?

Tags: hardware-failure, dvd, optical-drive, blu-ray

I have an issue with my optical drive (DVD/Blu-Ray). It fails to read specific discs always at specific points on those discs. For example one disc always fails at the 49.5% point. Some other discs fail at other points, again consistently. Can this be due to a faulty optical drive or is it necessarily an issue with the particular discs in question?

My impression is that a faulty optical drive should fail at random locations on discs. What I'm experiencing sounded more like issues with the specific discs in question. However, the fact that several different discs all give such errors which made me wonder whether this may be a general problem with my drive.

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: There may be a problem with the general storage and handling of the discs. Can you see dirt and scratches on them? If so, you can use a slightly damp, clean microfibre cloth to clean them: wipe from the middle to towards the edge, turn it round a bit, wipe again from the middle to the edge, and repeat all the way round.

Comment: Also try a disk lens cleaner